# Running multiple parpool jobs on a cluster

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, slurm

I am trying to run a number of MATLAB jobs on a cluster.
Since MATLAB saves states and diaries of each parpool job in ~/.matlab/... , when I run multiple jobs on a cluster, (each job using its own parpool), then MATLAB despite the fact that I close every open parpool every time I use one, it gives me errors related to "found 5 pre-existing parallel jobs..."

Is there a way to change the preferences folder of MATLAB for each instance of MATLAB so that this conflict does not arise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite `JobStorageLocation` property with a unique path for each job before starting parallel pool, e.g.

```
pc = parcluster('local'); % or whatever cluster you're running your jobs on
pc.JobStorageLocation = 'C:\my\unique\job\storage\location';
parpool(pc);
```